# c++ header and cpp file

Tags: c++, header

```
#ifndef Rand
#define Rand

#include<cstdlib>

class Rand{
public:
    int RandomGenerator();

private:
    int random = rand()%9+1;
};
#endif
```

This is the Header file

```
#include "Rand.h"

using namespace std;

int Rand::RandomGenerator()
{
    return random;
}
```

This is the CPP file

And in CPP file that function said random is undefined, and I have no idea why

Comment: `class Rand{` and `DrawUI::RandomGenerator()`???

Comment: The class is named `Rand`. The symbol `DrawUI` is just part of the [header include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) which is unrelated to your class.

Comment: Also, that's not a very good pseudo-random generator, it's no better than [this one](https://xkcd.com/221/), or [this one](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25).

Comment: Shit sorry for those mistake, i cauz it is not my original code, and when i copy the code and paste here, I did some edit on the code when post in here but forget to edit all lol

Comment: Allways make macros all uppercase. Don't make anything else all uppercase.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say "rand" is undefined?  You're not using namespace std in the header.

Comment: `#define Rand` followed by `class Rand` will give you trouble; the class has no name, because `Rand` gets replaced by an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#ifndef RAND_H
#define RAND_H

#include<cstdlib>

class Rand{
public:
    int RandomGenerator();

private:
    int random = rand()%9+1;
};
#endif
```

Allways make macros all uppercase. Don't make anything else all uppercase. If you `#define Rand` your `class Rand {` will be `class {`.

Comment: you should mention the proper way to generate random numbers in C++.